# TABLE with no vertical cell borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like my HTML table to only show the horizontal cell borders. Is there a way where I can hide the vertical cell borders?

Answer (score 28):

You can add strictly horizontal border lines by styling `tr` tags via CSS.

Example CSS:

```
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}​
```

Of course, you can use any border style/width/color you choose.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/

Comment: For me this only works when you change the tr to td in the above css

Comment: Same, I was not able to have this work with the <tr> tag in Safari or Chrome?

Comment: ``table, tr {
 border: 1px solid black;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
} ``

This works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 9):

```
table, th, td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using old-style `<table border="1">`, make it `<table border="1" rules="rows">`.

Comment: Take care - not compatible for all browsers example IE

Comment: Uh... since when? This is HTML 3.2, I'd be worried if IE didn't support it!

Comment: table rules are not supported in HTML5

Comment: @MaxStrater That's why I started with "assuming you are using old-style borders"

Comment: I didn't notice that, but it's still useful information going forward.

Answer (score 8):

I finally figured this out, you need to put `border-collapse` property in style of `table`!

CSS:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

And your table will only have horizontal lines!

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
  td {border-left: 1px solid black;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Answer (score -7):

You can add strictly horizontal border lines by styling tr tags via CSS.

```
<TABLE 
    BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=1 
    RULES=COLS FRAME=BOX
>
```

Comment: RULES="COLS" does the opposite. You meant CSS, but your example shows html attributes.

Comment: Horrable practices, no commas, everything uppercase...tsc tsc tsc